# Passing a value from one function to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, session, variables

I'm attempting to pass the value of a variable generated in the Button1 click event in a try { } to another function (function2).  What is the most efficient way to do this?  A Session object?

```
private static string createAuthCode()
{
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] buff = new byte[5];
    rng.GetBytes(buff);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code
    //..
    try {
    ...
    string authCode = createAuthCode();
    }
    //code
    //..
    function2();
}

protected void function2()
{
    //I want to access authCode here
}
```

Comment: can you not change the signature of `function2`? If `function2` is meant to be called from `Button1_Click` only, then why not pass it as parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use parameter like Manish Mishra suggested?

In Button1_Click, call function2 like this

```
function2(authCode);
```

Change your function2 to this:

```
protected void function2(String authCode)
{
    //access authCode here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If passing arguments to the subsequent method call isn't an option, you should use [`HttpContext.Current.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx). It's an in-memory collection of objects which lasts once the request ends (or in other words, it's a per-request storage).